# 'MapboxDirectionsInvoker' does not implement abstract member 'MapboxService.BaseUrl()' Xamarin Bindings Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mapbox-android

I am trying to bind the full Mapbox Navigation UI SDK 0.42 - There are multiple issues as it is a multiple jar/aar project as can be seen here at the following git: https://github.com/JacquesOkes/Mapbox-NavigationApp-Xamarin

I have been through most of the errors, but at the end when I want to implement the final project into a Xamarin.Android project, I get errors in the android that 4 interfaces are not present.

I have thus decided to go back to the individual bindings are revisit - I have removed my "remove-node" tags and am trying to solve each problem bit by bit. I will be posting a few of these questions as the next problem arrises.

First problem:[image]

The "hides" inherited abstract member needs to be overridden, it is currently:
[image]
If I change the src file directly to protected **override** and both errors are gone.

I would like to do this in meta so I dont have to change them each time I build. I added the following meta in:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.api.directionsrefresh.v1']/class[@name='MapboxDirectionsRefresh']/method[@name='baseUrl' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected override</attr>
```

The second I build with **override** in the meta it adds a second override to the src build.

How do I add an override to meta and ensure it will only add it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract member - no need to implement, can remove-node and works 100% with completed bindings.